# Photon Exception: Write failed. Custom type not found: UnityEngine.GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

Hey Guys I have some problem about Photon. Here is The code;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;

public class FinishManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Legs"))
        {
            collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PhotonView>().RPC("Win", RpcTarget.All, collision.gameObject); /*Here is the error line*/
        }
    }


    [PunRPC]
    public void Win(GameObject player)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.Destroy(player);
    }

}
```

The problem is this:

Exception: Write failed. Custom type not found: UnityEngine.GameObject
ExitGames.Client.Photon.Protocol18.WriteCustomType (ExitGames.Client.Photon.StreamBuffer stream, System.Object value, System.Boolean writeType) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/Protocol18Write.cs:732)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.Protocol18.Write (ExitGames.Client.Photon.StreamBuffer stream, System.Object value, ExitGames.Client.Photon.Protocol18+GpType gpType, System.Boolean writeType) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/Protocol18Write.cs:96)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.Protocol18.Write (ExitGames.Client.Photon.StreamBuffer stream, System.Object value, System.Boolean writeType) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/Protocol18Write.cs:26)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.Protocol18.WriteObjectArray (ExitGames.Client.Photon.StreamBuffer stream, System.Collections.IList array, System.Boolean writeType) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/Protocol18Write.cs:639)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.Protocol18.Write (ExitGames.Client.Photon.StreamBuffer stream, System.Object value, ExitGames.Client.Photon.Protocol18+GpType gpType, System.Boolean writeType) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/Protocol18Write.cs:156)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.Protocol18.Write (ExitGames.Client.Photon.StreamBuffer stream, System.Object value, System.Boolean writeType) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/Protocol18Write.cs:26)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.Protocol18.WriteHashtable (ExitGames.Client.Photon.StreamBuffer stream, System.Object value, System.Boolean writeType) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/Protocol18Write.cs:431)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.Protocol18.Write (ExitGames.Client.Photon.StreamBuffer stream, System.Object value, ExitGames.Client.Photon.Protocol18+GpType gpType, System.Boolean writeType) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/Protocol18Write.cs:129)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.Protocol18.Write (ExitGames.Client.Photon.StreamBuffer stream, System.Object value, System.Boolean writeType) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/Protocol18Write.cs:26)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.Protocol18.WriteParameterTable (ExitGames.Client.Photon.StreamBuffer stream, ExitGames.Client.Photon.ParameterDictionary parameters) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/Protocol18Write.cs:238)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.Protocol18.SerializeOperationRequest (ExitGames.Client.Photon.StreamBuffer stream, System.Byte operationCode, ExitGames.Client.Photon.ParameterDictionary parameters, System.Boolean setType) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/Protocol18Write.cs:273)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.PeerBase.SerializeOperationToMessage (System.Byte opCode, ExitGames.Client.Photon.ParameterDictionary parameters, ExitGames.Client.Photon.EgMessageType messageType, System.Boolean encrypt) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/PeerBase.cs:683)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.PhotonPeer.SendOperation (System.Byte operationCode, ExitGames.Client.Photon.ParameterDictionary operationParameters, ExitGames.Client.Photon.SendOptions sendOptions) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/PhotonPeer.cs:1863)
Photon.Realtime.LoadBalancingPeer.OpRaiseEvent (System.Byte eventCode, System.Object customEventContent, Photon.Realtime.RaiseEventOptions raiseEventOptions, ExitGames.Client.Photon.SendOptions sendOptions) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonRealtime/Code/LoadbalancingPeer.cs:965)
Photon.Realtime.LoadBalancingClient.OpRaiseEvent (System.Byte eventCode, System.Object customEventContent, Photon.Realtime.RaiseEventOptions raiseEventOptions, ExitGames.Client.Photon.SendOptions sendOptions) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonRealtime/Code/LoadBalancingClient.cs:2176)
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork.RaiseEventInternal (System.Byte eventCode, System.Object eventContent, Photon.Realtime.RaiseEventOptions raiseEventOptions, ExitGames.Client.Photon.SendOptions sendOptions) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetwork.cs:2351)
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork.RPC (Photon.Pun.PhotonView view, System.String methodName, Photon.Pun.RpcTarget target, Photon.Realtime.Player player, System.Boolean encrypt, System.Object[] parameters) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetworkPart.cs:1263)
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork.RPC (Photon.Pun.PhotonView view, System.String methodName, Photon.Pun.RpcTarget target, System.Boolean encrypt, System.Object[] parameters) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetwork.cs:2940)
Photon.Pun.PhotonView.RPC (System.String methodName, Photon.Pun.RpcTarget target, System.Object[] parameters) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonView.cs:604)
FinishManager.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D collision) (at Assets/FinishManager.cs:13)

Comment: Since you are using PhotonNetwork.Destroy, this only needs to be called one time, and no RPC is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use PhotonNetwork.Destroy if the object was created using PhotonNetwork.Instantiate, regardless of it having a photon view component.

From Docs:

> Destroying networked objects works only if they got created with PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(). Objects loaded with a scene are ignored, no matter if they have PhotonView components.

The client who is calling PhotonNetwork.Destroy must have control of the object being destroyed.

If your FinishManager component has control of the object, you can simply call Destroy when the collision happens.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Legs"))
    {
        var photonView = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        if (photonView)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.Destroy(photonView);
        }
    }
}
```

If your FinishManager does not have control of the object, the object in question will need to initiate Destroy iteself.  For this you can use an RPC.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Legs"))
    {
        var photonView = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        if (photonView)
        {
            photonView.RPC("DestroyMyself", photonView.Owner);
        }
    }
}
```

The RPC method needs to be on the object that was instantiated.

```
[PunRPC]
private void DestroyMyself()
{
    PhotonNetwork.Destroy(gameObject);
}
```